No record of mac address and no vendor id when searching mac address
When looking at my wifi modem router logins i noticed an unusual mac address for an unfamiliar device, so i looked up the mac adress and it said ALERT NO RECORD FOUND NO VENDOR. What does this mean? I presumed it was my new phones mac address but wouldnt that have a vendor ID. Its a vivo21Y phone.
What does it mean if there is no record of the MAC address? No vendor etc?

does the first part of the MAC look like x2, x6, xA or xE

What is the MAC address?

in short it means that the OUI code in the leading 24 bytes of the Media Access Control Address are not listed on whatever database of registered network device vendors that the modem is configure to use.
OUIs are requested/registered with the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) Registration Authority. There are many databases and web-services that list registered OUIDs available for use by software and devices.
So ultimately the device in question may be made by an organization that feels no need to register an OUI, or your modem may be using an outdated or incomplete datasource when attempting to fingerprint network devices.
